# Use more recent API in older device

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, android-8.0-oreo

I would like to use one of the new features of Android 8.0 Oreo : the `onRangeStart` method of the `UtteranceProgressListener` class. However, it doesn't seem to work on older devices (Android 6.0 Marshmallow), even with the latest Google TTS APK installed.

Is it normal ? Android Studio doesn't force me to do any API version check, so I assumed it would work on all Android versions. Would it be possible to hack my way around this to have a similar feature, since the Google TTS app now uses the `rangeStart` method ? With the Xposed framework maybe ? (would I be allowed to ?)

Comment: "Is it normal ?" -- if by "it" you mean "the Android SDK adding new classes and methods with each API level", then yes, it is normal. "since the Google TTS app now uses the rangeStart method ?" -- I doubt that it uses `onRangeStart()` on older versions of Android. That method does not exist, nor does anything in the framework appear to call that method on older versions of Android, based on [a search of the Android 7.1 source](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-7.1.2_r33/search?q=onRangeStart&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&type=&project=frameworks).

Comment: I meant to ask is it normal that I can't use it, I have my answer then. By looking at the latest Google TTS engine APK source code, I can see that is calls `rangeStart` but it must be an empty method since it's not in the 7.1 framework.

Comment: Also note that you may be conflating `onRangeStart()` with `rangeStart()`.

Comment: `onRangeStart` is the callback in the utterance listener, `rangeStart` is the actual method called by the TTS engine

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will force you to do API version checs in the future stable releases.